# Is this thinking accurate on ESB vs. REST-styled interfaces?

Tags: rest, soap, esb

To tie together various legacy applications, some mainframe-based, I'm trying to compare using an ESB like MQSeries, a WS-* approach, or something more RESTful.

Is there much substance to the idea that writing the interface to REST, instead of MQ or even WS-*, may have a secondary benefit of also taking us closer to web-enabling portions of the apps (for use by humans with browsers)?

Comment: MQSeries/WebSphere MQ has attributes of an ESB, like moderate transformation capabilities, much like Microsoft's BizTalk, but is not in and of itself a standalone, fully-featured ESB. Also REST vs ESB is apples vs oranges. SOAP or REST are protocols. ESB is an implemented system for messaging and transformation that may use SOAP or REST in various fashions.

Answer (score 1):

Applications have been web-enabled for years before REST bacame a fad, and will do for years to come. I don't see much of a relationship between the two.

BTW, I didn't think of MQSeries as having to do with ESB - it's just a message queueing system, largely equivalent to MSMQ.